# How to output postgresql field names into dictionary instead of just outputting the column names in python?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, dictionary

I have an sql query and I would like to output the postgresql field names into a dictionary instead of just outputting the column names in python? Does anyone know how to do that? I would greatly appreciate your help!

```
'''SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_notBefore(c.certificate), x509_notAfter(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_keyAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_keySize(c.certificate), x509_publicKeyMD5(c.certificate), x509_publicKey(c.certificate), x509_rsaModulus(c.certificate), x509_serialNumber(c.certificate), x509_signatureHashAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_signatureKeyAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_subjectName(c.certificate), x509_name(c.certificate), x509_name_print(c.certificate), x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_subjectKeyIdentifier(c.certificate), x509_extKeyUsages(c.certificate), x509_certPolicies(c.certificate), x509_canIssueCerts(c.certificate), x509_getPathLenConstraint(c.certificate), x509_altNames(c.certificate), x509_altNames_raw(c.certificate), x509_cRLDistributionPoints(c.certificate), x509_authorityInfoAccess(c.certificate), x509_print(c.certificate), x509_anyNamesWithNULs(c.certificate), x509_extensions(c.certificate), x509_tbscert_strip_ct_ext(c.certificate), x509_hasROCAFingerprint(c.certificate)
                        FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE
                        c.id= ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) =
                        lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''', (domain_name,))
```

Comment: Can you provide how sql looks like? Do you have any input data? How many fields are involved?

Comment: @mad_ Thanks for your help! I have included my sql statement in my original post now. I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Which driver are you using? What have you tried so far? If you using psycopg then it would be worth to check this out http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html

Comment: @mad_ Thank you for your response! I'm using psycopg2

Answer (score 0):

Like @mad_ suggested, this should work:

You would need to establish a connection prior, and then using said connection you can just follow along

```
SQL = '''
    SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate) as common_name, 
          x509_issuerName(c.certificate) as issuer_name, 
          x509_notBefore(c.certificate) as not_before
    FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci 
    WHERE c.id = ci.certificate_id 
         AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' 
         AND lower(ci.name_value) = lower(%s) 
         AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()
'''
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
cursor.execute(SQL, (domain_name,))
# This will contain a list [{'id': 1, 'common_name': 'something...', ....}]
your_dict_data = cursor.fetchall()
```

But if you're just going to display it on some kind of table format, i suggest you use `NamedTupleCursor` instead.

```
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor)
cursor.execute(SQL, (domain_name,))

for certificate in cursor.fetchall():
    print(certificate.id)
    print(certificate.common_name)
    print(certificate.issuer_name)
```

*I removed a lot of your columns more than anything because it would be time consuming going through all your columns and renaming them.. so.. that task i leave to you*

Comment: *this should work*...what should work? Please explain to OP and future readers the solution you employed.